# Use two columns for unique entry identification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have dataframe of four columns

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns="EmployeeName","JobTitle","TotalPayBenefits","Year"])
```

I want to find unique entries in the dataframe based on the columns "EmployeeName" and "JobTitle" considering both of them simultaneously.

I tried concatenating the fields

```
df["EmployeeName"].concatenate(df2011["JobTitle"])
```

But it didn't help. Need help figuring out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
df2[~df2[["EmployeeName","JobTitle"]].duplicated()]
```

Comment: Thanks colonel but with this it gives out the dataframe with a modified index column .. Is there a way to get it without that.. I can do that by picking the columns and putting in a new dataframe but anything built in

Comment: it gives you a dataframe with unique pairs in the wanted column with lines marked with original index. You can chain `.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the index if needed.